# How do I remove many to many link between 2 EF Ojects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have a Many to many relationship in my EF.  I want to remove the link between 2 of the objects but leave the rest of the relationships intact.

Is there a way to do this with out using a stored procedure or executeStoreQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? If you have two objects related in many-to-many relationship both have collection navigation property so removing is done by:

```
entityA.RelatedEntities.Remove(entityB);
```

Where `entityA` is your first object `RelatedEntities` is collection of related objects and `entityB` is the object you want to remove from relation.

Comment: That seems to delete Entity B when i implement

Comment: No it should not delete entityB.

Comment: That was what i thought too...